# Academia.SX-like question(s) on Slashdot

Tags: discussion

https://news.slashdot.org/story/18/11/06/1452238/ask-slashdot-how-to-fix-an-outdated-college-tech-curriculum

An anonymous reader writes:

> As a student, what's the best way to bring change to an outdated
>   college tech curriculum?
>
> The background on this is that I have 15 years of experience in the
>   field and a very healthy amount of industry-recognized training and
>   certifications. I'm merely finishing up my degree to flesh out my
>   resume -- I haven't learned much from the program that I don't already
>   know. However, the program would have benefited me greatly 15 years
>   ago. It's a great program, except for a biometrics class that is
>   absolutely behind the curve. The newest publication on the syllabus is
>   from 2009. This is simply teaching the students outdated and often
>   wrong information.
>
> Additionally, a lot of the material seems like it was stretched to
>   make a full semester class in biometrics in the first place -- most of
>   the material, honestly, could be compressed to about two hours of
>   lecture and still be delivered at a reasonable rate.
>
> What's the best way for a student in my situation to get this fixed so
>   the school stops wasting student's time with outdated and wrong
>   information?

I very much suggest reading some of the replies/comments there - and not just the highest-rated ones.

What do you think about:

1. The way answers are penned and commented on over there as opposed to on Academia.SX.
2. Whether Academia.SX should make those kind of questions (i.e. on another site, but in an Q&A+comments format similar to what we have here) accessible somehow to people searching on Academia.SX?

Comment: So... is this a question? Sounds kind of like a general announcement...

Comment: @eykanal: See edit.

Comment: 1) Stack Exchange is not a discussion board, so I'm not sure what do you mean by "... as opposed to discussions here"? 2) as of whether this question is on-topic or not, I'll leave it to this community to decide (I'm just a passer-by)

Comment: Re: 1. See edit.

Comment: This is a very broad question as it currently stands and isn't really answerable. Since this is meta and not the main site, I'll leave this open for now so you can make edits, but if we can't figure out how to make this question more specific we'll probably end up closing it.

Answer (score 3):

> The way answers are penned and commented on over there as opposed to on Academia.SX

I've tried to read various topics on Sladshot in the past but I find it very hard to follow responses in such a format. I've thus stopped following any discussion there a long time ago. Honestly, it just pisses me off (disclaimer: I'm an old fart and I don't like certain forms of communication).

> Whether Academia.SX should make those kind of questions (i.e. on another site, but in an Q&A+comments format similar to what we have here) accessible somehow to people searching on Academia.SX?

I think that our chat is the right place to post links to posts, documents and discussions about the academic world that can be found elsewhere. There are already many examples of such links.

Comment: So, thanks for your second suggestion. Unfortunately, the negative vote count on the question doesn't suggest people are very thrilled about seeing these links.

Comment: @einpoklum At the moment, there is just one negative vote on your question and I wouldn't read too much into this (it might be due just to the way the question is formulated). The good thing about the chat is that you really don't need community consensus to post links that may be of interest there.

Comment: @einpoklum don't worry about a few down votes. That said, chat is probably the best place for links like that. I have posted links in chat to stuff I like.